# HTML5 drag and drop setDragImage

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, draggable

I am trying to set the drag image of the cursor when dragging an image, however I am not seeing the image when I start to drag, am I doing something wrong?

```
 var dragIcon = document.createElement("img");
 var src = this.$el.find("img").attr("src");
 dragIcon.src = src.replace("http://domain.dev", "");
 dragIcon.width = 100;
 console.log(dragIcon);
 e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, -10, -10);
```

`this.$el` looks like this,

```
<div class="person-card column" draggable="true" id="95">
        <img class="person-card-image" src="/profile_pictures/default.png">
        <div class="card-header-title single">
            <a href="/people/person/95">John Doe</a>
        </div>
        <div class="person-card-subtitle">

                Linked

        </div>
        <!--<div class="person-card-invite is-sent">
            <a href="#">Invite</a>
        </div>-->
    </div>
```

I cannot see any reason why this would not work. However I notice I I look in the dom i do not think the new img is being created.

Comment: Add dragIcon.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);

Answer (score 1):

From what I have been investigating. You need to append the image in your document. In Firefox, you can safely set a position: absolute then top: -9999px. However, in Chrome, you will have the image on the page as well. The trick would be to hide it behind something another position absolute.

Maybe there is a better way for Chrome, I am still trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to hack this. Create a wrapper div with

```
position:absolute, width:0px; Height:0px; top:0px; right:0px
```

and create control on dragstart event with

```
position:relative
```

bind the control to the wrapper and set the control to the setDragImage.